# knockout foreach based on another observable

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have an an observable and few observable arrays. I want to iterate of of these observable arrays depending on what observable do I have. How cryptic does it sound. If it is, than this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uP27x/) will make it super simple

```
function VM(){
    var self = this;
    this.type1 = ko.observableArray(['Hello', 'this', 'is', 'first', 'array']);
    this.type2 = ko.observableArray(['Second', 'Array']);
    this.type3 = ko.observableArray(['hohoho', 'hahaha']);

    this.type = ko.observable('type1')

    this.setType = function(t){
        self.type(t);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM())
```

So depending on which button do I click, I want different arrays to be iterated.

```
<button data-bind="click: function(){setType('type1')}">Type1</button>
<button data-bind="click: function(){setType('type2')}">Type2</button>
<button data-bind="click: function(){setType('type3')}">Type3</button>

<div data-bind='text: type'></div><br>

<ul data-bind="foreach: type1">
    <li data-bind="text: $data">
</ul>
```

As you see, clicking on the button change observable, but I can not change array which will be iterated. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `ul` to look like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: $root[type()]">
    <li data-bind="text: $data">
</ul>
```

`$root` is supplied by `knockout`, and refers to the object originally specified to the `ko.applyBindings` call.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is with a computed...

```
this.selectedType = ko.computed(function() {
    return self[self.type()]();
});

<ul data-bind="foreach: selectedType">
    <li data-bind="text: $data">
</ul>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3EAZc/)